# Javascript - Wait a set time before running script only once

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I Have a notification box that pops up when a user click's on a link. I have decided to change this so that the pop up comes up automatically after a set time.

```
<div id="container">
</p>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" id="add-sticky">Add sticky notification</a>: Doesn't run on a fade timer.  Just sits there until the user manually removes it by clicking on the (X).       
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" id="remove-all">Remove all notifications</a>        
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is the original Link that i had on site. I have another Javascript file that listens for the add-sticky ID. (This works perfectly fine). This is the javascript file that runs the automatic popup

```
setInterval("popup()", 2000 );
function popup() {
           var el = document.getElementById('add-sticky');



// Firefox
if (document.createEvent) {
var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
event.initEvent("click", true, true);
el.dispatchEvent(event);
}
// IE
else if (el.click) {
el.click();

}

           }
```

This however makes the pop run activate over and over again just files up the page. How can i get the pop up to run about 30secs after landing on page and then wait for about a min before running another pop up?

Apart from what i got i cannot seem to get it to do this. Any help you be great

Bobby

Comment: Use `setTimout` instead of `setInterval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use setTimeout instead if you just want to execute the pop up twice

```
setTimeout(popup, 30000); // 30 seconds
function popup() {
    // Show your popup

    // if (needToShowPopUpAgain)
           setTimeout(popup, 60000); // 1 minute



}
```

Comment: thank you very much, if i wanted to set it so it just continuously popped up every 1 min after what would i need to change?

Comment: If you do want continuos popup, I would use setInterval. You can cancel setInterval whenever by calling clearInterval.